is_category() not firing in functions.php
In functions.php I want to enqueue scripts based on what page I'm viewing: home page, single page, etc.
It all seems to work except when I go on a blog category.
I tried the following (in functions.php):
is_front_page() -> works
is_page() -> works
is_single() -> works
is_category() -> NOPE.

    function load_ngof_files() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'ngof_common', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/com.css');
    
    if (is_front_page()) {
        // echo "front page";   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ngof_front', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/front.css');

    } elseif (is_category()) {
        echo "category";
        wp_enqueue_style( 'ngof_cat', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/cat.css');

    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo "page";

    } elseif (is_single()) {
        // Blog posts index page
        echo "single";
    }
    
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_ngof_files' );

Any ideas why? category.php is called correctly.

If instead of binding to "wp_enqueue_scripts" I bind to "wp" it works, but is that correct?

The wp_enqueue_scripts action hook is after the wp action hook, so if it works there it should also work later, unless the global $wp_query is being changed to make the is_category() conditional break. Recommend using Query Monitor plugin to assist with debugging.

It started working, not sure what was wrong.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
